# Update a progress bar in mathematica

Tags: progress-bar, wolfram-mathematica

during the computation I would update the value of progress bar to notify to the user the progress of the computation.

Unfortunately I'm not able to do this because when I call SetPropertyValue function

```
ref@SetPropertyValue[{"bar", "value"}, 70];
```

the value isn't updated.

I obtain ref in this way

```
ref = GUIRun[mainWindow];
```

Answer (score 9):

With Mathematica 6 or later try using Monitor and ProgressIndicator instead of the older GUIKit package:

```
With[{count = 1000}, 
 Monitor[Do[Pause[0.01];, {i, count}], 
  ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[i/count]]]]
```

Comment: The problem is that I would updatethe progress indicator in the computation, and I can't predict computation time, so I would update progress indicator status dinamically, for example when occurring some events.

How can I do this ?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your followup question. The i/count expression inside Dynamic is reevaluated whenever i or count changes.  So you don't have to know what count is ahead of time since you can just update its value during the computation.  Also, the second argument to Monitor doesn't have to be a ProgressIndicator.  If you don't know the maximum value you'll be using, but you still want to monitor the evaluation you could use something like Dynamic[i] and the current value of i will be displayed and updated.

Answer (score 6):

This is just an extension to @ragfield's answer.

If you want to represent bounded and unbounded magnitudes, you colud do something along these lines:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
count = 0; inRange = 0; i = 0; sumTgt = 10^5
Monitor[
  While[count < sumTgt,
   If[.14 < (rand = RandomReal[]) < .15, inRange++];
   count += rand;
  ]
  , {{"SumTillNow", ProgressIndicator[count,   {0, sumTgt}  ],count},
     {"InRange",    ProgressIndicator[inRange, Indeterminate],inRange}} 
   // MatrixForm
];
```

If you want to save the progress indicators as an animated gif for presententations and the such, you could modify it a bit:

```
count = 0; inRange = 0; i = 0; sumTgt = 10^4
Monitor[
  While[count < sumTgt,
   If[.14 < (rand = RandomReal[]) < .15, inRange++];
   count += rand;
  ]
  , a[++i] = Grid[
                 {{"SumTillNow", ProgressIndicator[count, {0, sumTgt}],count},       
                  {"InRange", ProgressIndicator[inRange, Indeterminate],inRange + 0.}},
              Frame -> All, Alignment -> {{Left, Center, Right}}, 
              ItemSize -> {{Automatic, Automatic, 8}}];
];
Export["c:\Anim.gif", Table[a[j]//MatrixForm, {j, i}],"DisplayDurations"->{.3}]
```

and the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to execute

```
Needs["GUIKit`"];
```

before starting to use the GUIKit ?  If not your commands won't execute, because they are not known.  If you load the GUIKit after you start using it, don't forget that some of its symbols may be shadowed by the symbols you have inadvertently defined.